# Build image location in Crystal Report from report location

Tags: scripting, crystal-reports

I'm using Crystal Reports to generate report definition ***.rpt** files. I later create reports using those definition files from inside my application.

I have a special image called the **logo** that sits in my application's file directory. I'd like to reference this logo on my crystal report. The logo is always located a couple directories up from my report, but the root directory and the host computer can change between installations, so the file structure could look like this:

```
image: c:\files\logo.png
report: c:\files\reports\type1\myreport.rpt
```

or like this:

```
image: \\filehost\files\logo.png
report: \\filehost\\files\reports\type1\myreport.rpt
```

**Does Crystal have a way to reference this image in a formula with a relative path?** Does the .rpt file contain a reference to it's file location that I could build off of to grab this image?

**Edit:** @campagnolo_1 mentions that Crystal has a "File Path and Name" special field, but I don't see a way to use that in the image file location script.

**Edit 2:** @campagnolo_1 has provided a solution in the comments on his answer. Thanks campagnolo_1!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crystal has a special field for the file path and name. You could use that to find out where the report file is located and extract the path if needed. Then you can use that to dynamically reference your image file. Here is a [post](http://cogniza.com/wordpress/2010/03/15/crystal-reports-dynamic-images/) with some step-by-step instructions.

Comment: I didn't realize that Crystal has a special field for that, but I don't see any way to get that information into the image object's script. I can't seem to reference special fields from the script interface.

Comment: I think it's something you'll have to do within the report itself. You will have to create a formula (fileLocation) for the file location that only has "FileName" in it. This will give you the full path of the report. As the post I referenced stated, insert a picture. In the picture tab of the format editor add a formula for the Graphic Location that would be something like: if left({@fileLocation), "C:\") > 0 then ..... Do you understand what I'm getting at?

Comment: I just investigated further and discovered that while I can't reference special fields from the field explorer, I can reference the built-in FileName _function_ that you mention in your comment. This will provide the information that I need to construct the path to my image as you suggested.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I always stream my logos in as part of the underlying data that the report is bound against. I add the column to the dataset by doing something like this:

```
DataTable dt = GetYourDataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("imagepath", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("image", typeof(System.Byte[])));             
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
```

And populate it with:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(szFilePath, FileMode.Open))
{
    using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
    {
          foreach (DataRow dr in _dtReportData.Rows)
          {
               dr["imagepath"] = szFilePath;
               dr["image"] = br.ReadBytes((int)br.BaseStream.Length);
          }
    }
}
```

I know it's redundant to set EVERY ROW, but it does work, and the object can just be added to the report as a Blob.

The big advantage for you would be that the image location is arbitrary.. you only need to know it at data-retrieval time, not at report-rendering time.

Comment: I would be happy to accept this answer, but I specifically need to work within the bounds of the rpt file / the crystal report scripting.

Comment: I figured it may not be an option. Thanks for following up; I'll let this here for posterity.